# Why does "set ruler" get reset to noruler?

Tags: linux

I have `set ruler` in my `.vimrc`.

If I run `vim` and then `:verbose set ruler?` to check the status of this setting, on Ubuntu Linux it says :

```
noruler
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

At the bash prompt, `grep` says :

```
$ grep ruler .vimrc 
set ruler
```

And on Debian Linux, `:verbose set ruler?` says :

```
noruler
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
```

At the bash prompt, `grep` says :

```
$ grep ruler /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time
```

Why does `set ruler` get reset to `noruler` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if `set paste?` and `set compatible?` are set.

If they are set, disable them. `ruler` is reset if they are set.
More details at `:help ruler`

Answer (score 2):

I found after finding the above answer, that my paste was set, but my compatible wasn't set. Although after I moved set ruler to a place below the set paste I was able to get my ruler back, and have paste enabled for justified pasting of code.

Comment: you should not globally enable paste. It's a workaround that should only be enabled before actually pasting, because it changes too many things